# Solve the ode $W^{\prime }\left( s\right) -2iH\left( s\right) W\left( s\right) -1=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider the differential equation

> > $W^{\prime }\left( s\right) -2iH\left( s\right) W\left( s\right) -1=0$, $%
> > s\in I\subset 
> > \mathbb{R}
> > $

and consider the functions

> > $F\left( s\right) =\int\limits_{0}^{s}\sin \left(
> > 2\int\limits_{0}^{u}H\left( t\right) dt\right) du$
> >
> > $G\left( s\right) =\int\limits_{0}^{s}\cos \left(
> > 2\int\limits_{0}^{u}H\left( t\right) dt\right) du$

where $H:I\rightarrow 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$ is functions real of one variable

Show that the general solution to the above differential equation is given by

> > $W\left( s\right) =\left\{ \left( F\left( s\right) -c_{1}\right) +i\left(
> > G\left( s\right) +c_{2}\right) \right\} \left( F^{\prime }\left( s\right)
> > -iG^{\prime }\left( s\right) \right) $

Can anyone help me solve this differential equation? Well I just know the ode's that I know do not have complex coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You treat the equation as if it were real. Multiply by $\exp\bigl(-2\,i\int_0^sH(t)\,dt\bigr)$ to get
$$
\Bigl(\exp\bigl(-2\,i\int_0^sH(t)\,dt\bigr)\,W\Bigr)'=\exp\bigl(-2\,i\int_0^sH(t)\,dt\bigr).
$$
Integrate and remember that
$$
\exp\Bigl(-2\,i\int_0^sH(t)\,dt\Bigr)=\cos\Bigl(2\int_0^sH(t)\,dt\Bigr)-\sin\Bigl(2\int_0^sH(t)\,dt\Bigr)i.
$$

Comment: I may be mistaken, but this derivative is strange. Why the derivative of $\int_0^sH(t)dt$ with respect to $s$ is not necessarily $H$. Unless it is in relation to $t$, but if it is in relation to $t$ we do not get the equality above

Comment: The fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that if $f$ is continuous, then$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)\,dt=f(x).$$